# (random?) 500 errors in Magento front and backend - version 1.4.1.1

Tags: magento, fastcgi, magento-1.4

i need your help once again :)

For some time now i get strange 500 errors in the front and backend of magento. I use magento 1.4.1.1.

The errors can appear everywhere, anytime. I get about 10-20 of them every day. The errorlog reads something like this:
[Wed Oct 17 16:02:19 2012] [warn] [client 93.219.97.29] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: /index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/1617/
[Wed Oct 17 16:02:19 2012] [warn] [client 93.219.97.29] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function, referer: http://www.xxxx.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/1617/

I have attached a screenshot of the error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X0ns.jpg

Do you guys have any idea what i can do? Thank you very much :)

Greets

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving similar errors on 1.7.0.2 community edition on a Ubuntu 10.04 LTS LAMP server. In my case (using Virtualmin) I had incorrectly set the virtual server to run php in FastCGI as the website owner.  The apache user is different from the site owner, and magento multi-site install was setup to run as that apache user.

ALSO, I had uncommented Magento's profiler inside index.php `Varien_Profiler::enable();`
and turned on the profiler via Magento admin panel (System->Configuration->Developer.

Commenting out the profiler object AND reversing the change to php execution mode did the trick.

See attached for the proper virtualmin setting, found in Virtualmin->Server Configuration->Website Options[image: screen shot]